# Problems Installing RCurl package in R

Tags: r, package, libcurl, rcurl

I am trying to install the RCurl package in R 3.2.2 but when I run the command

```
install.packages("RCurl")
```

I get the following error:

> Warning in install.packages :
>         write error in extracting from zip file
>       Warning in install.packages :
>         cannot open compressed file 'RCurl/DESCRIPTION', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
>       Error in install.packages : cannot open the connection

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what OS are you on, and are you using Rstudio?

Comment: Have you tried using a different CRAN mirror?

Comment: Hi. I have tried using a different CRAN. Im on Windows 7 and yes I am using RStudio although I tried it in R and it also does not work.